# Force C++ program to pause in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging C++ program compiled with MSVC under Windows.
I want to investigate issue linked with multi threading. So I put ASSERT in my code and when program reaches ASSERT it displays window about ASSERT (Standart [Abort], [Retry], [Ignore] window) with proposal to pause program in debugger. I press [Retry] button and program pauses. BUT while I was pressing the button other threads continue to execute. 
So the question is how to immediately stop the program when it reaches some point to see what other threads was doing at that time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to set a conditional breakpoint instead of using an `assert`:

[image: breakpoint visual studio]

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to do it programmatically, use [DebugBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx). (C# has an equivalent api System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break)

In case you want to do it from ide, from the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx) you can put a breakpoint (or break all the application, ctrl+alt+B) from visual studio and then control the thread execution using "freeze" and "thaw" in the thread window.

Comment: Sometimes the compiler intrinsic __debugbreak() is preferred over DebugBreak (which is a kernel32 export), because the intrinsic is still reliable when MS System symbols are not loaded into the debugger.